# Student Contact Details - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

To write a SQL query that to display student information. If the address is missing, display the email id and vice-versa. If both the address and the email are missing then display 'NA'. It is clear that we should make use of CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE clauses. But the query is not fetching the desired values.

[image]

Comment: "But the query is not fetching the desired values." - what query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` as follows:

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    COALESCE(T.ADDRESS, T.EMAIL_ID, 'NA') AS CALCULATED_ADDRESS
FROM
    STUDENT_DETAILS T;
```